# float label not work on appending

Tags: jquery

I'm using float label and adding new items when clicking a button.
But when adding, the field float label added, stops running. Can someone help me?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 campos-cnpj--blocos">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group floatl">
     <label class="floatl__label">CNPJ</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="CNPJ" class="form-control floatl__input" value="0000000000">
   </div>
  <button class="btn-action-blue btn-add-ref">+</button>
  <button class="btn-action-blue btn-sub-ref">-</button>
 </div>
```

JQUERY

```
  (function cnpjBlocos(){

  $('.campos-cnpj--blocos').on('click' , '.btn-add-ref', function(e){
  var $floatLabel = "floatl__label"; 
  var $floatInput = "floatl__input";
  var $floatL = "floatl";

  $('.campos-cnpj--blocos').append(
  '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<div class="form-group '+$floatL+'">' +
      '<label class="'+$floatLabel+'">CNPJ</label>' +
      '<input type="text" placeholder="CNPJ" class="form-control '+$floatInput+'">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<button class="btn-action-blue btn-add-ref">+</button>' +
    '<button class="btn-action-blue btn-sub-ref">-</button>' +
  '</div>'
);
$(this).next('.btn-sub-ref').show();
$(this).hide();

$('.campos-cnpj--blocos').on('click', '.btn-sub-ref', function(e){
  $(this).closest('.col-md-3').hide();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(numberRef);
});

e.preventDefault();
});  
})();
```

Comment: This is not directly tied to your question, but I believe you came over to JavaScript from PHP or Shell, right? In JavaScript, you usually define variables without the `$` sign in front of it. Usually only jQuery objects get that prefix. This would apply to your variables `$floatLabel`, `$floatInput`, `$floatL` - which all just contain regular Strings.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. It would be easy to solve if you could provide a working JSFiddle.